# Rank SQL Equivalent in Exposed

Tags: sql, postgresql, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I want to show all restaurants with top 3 menu in each. Now im using this Query and works fine

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, m.id, m.name, m.sold
FROM restaurant r
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, name, resto_id, sold,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY resto_id ORDER BY sold DESC) AS row_num
    FROM menu_item
) AS m ON r.id = m.resto_id
WHERE m.row_num <= 3
ORDER BY r.id, m.row_num;
```

I just wondering what is equivalent of below query in Exposed
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY resto_id ORDER BY sold DESC) AS row_num`

Answer (score -1):

The following query is equivalent to the query you provided, but it uses the RANK() function instead of the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, m.id, m.name, m.sold,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY resto_id ORDER BY sold DESC) AS row_num
FROM restaurant r
LEFT JOIN menu_item m ON r.id = m.resto_id
WHERE m.row_num <= 3
ORDER BY r.id, m.row_num;
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer, could you provide the exposed equivalent?